# How to monitor a process that launches “dllhost.exe” and add process.exited in this dllhost.exe process?

Tags: c#, wpf, file

What I want: I have a wpf application , click a button, a file will be automatically opened. And after the opened file process is closed, the file should be deleted automatically.

What I did:

```
Process processMonitor = new Process();    
processMonitor.StartInfo.FileName = filePath; 
processMonitor.Exited += (sender,value) =>{ File.Delete(filePath); };
processMonitor.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
processMonitor.Start();
```

It works good when the filepath is not an image filepath.

But if the filepath was a image filepath, it will be opened by dllhost.exe process.

So, in `processMonitor.Start();` processMonitor is null.

Does someone have a better idea to achieve my intention? 
I guess it's difficult to operate dllhost.exe process. Because I use
`Process[] dllhostprocesslist = Process.GetProcessesByName("dllhost.exe");` to get dllhost.exe process list, the result list is Process[0].

So if the result is ok, whatever the method is ok.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If it was an acceptable compromise, you might want to consider P/Invoking `MoveFileEx` with `MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT` to perform the deletion. The file will persist a bit longer, but will be deleted during the next reboot - a time when you definitely know that whatever process you started is no longer running.

Comment: I did a little search about what you said. I believe it can satisfy my requirement. Can you give me some more information (some links, some codes) as answer? Thank you very much. I even didn't know `MoveFileEx` at all.

Comment: sorry,  @Damien_The_Unbeliever , too sad, it cant resolve my problem. `MoveFileEx` just can delete the file. Now my trouble is adding `Process.Exited` in dllhost.exe process when dllhost.exe process was raised.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you don't know what programs will launch in response to trying to run a file, there's no generic way to answer the question "has 'it' finished working with that file?". People can and do write application architectures in all kinds of interesting ways (E.g. the first process launched for a file may inspect the file, determine the program that should act on that file, scheduled that program to launch (for whatever reason) and then exit)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ,yes, you are right. the file and process or thread will be extended. But this is my customer's requirement. They don't want to keep those files. They usually use excel file or picture. I need to delete the file as much as possible. But now the picture will not be acted by a new process, so i cant add `process.Exited` event to delete that file. excel file and exe file , can be automatically deleted.